HPLIP 3.24.4 not detecting HP color Laserjet 3303sdw
HPLIP 3.24.4 not detecting the HP Color Laser 3303sdw whereas HP color Laser 4303 supported .
Please share any workaround so that support on HPLIP 3.24.4

Normally HP printers are automatically recognised by the OS without the need for HPLIP. Which version and Distro of Linux are you using? Please add that information into your question with [edit]

We are using HP LIP 3.24.4 version on Ubuntu 20.4 but its not detecting

"but its not detecting" HPLIP or the OS. Please be clear and add to your question, don't add to the comments which are for us to ask you questions for clarification.

Hi Graham, Thanks for pitching in..........Just need to know whether HP Color Laser 3303 supported on ubuntu 20 or more  bcz in supported models that model is not listed on HPLIP resulting it is not detecting on USB. I am not too sure whether HPLIP 3.24.4 is compatible with this printer, or some other patch is required. Ideally if driver is available it should detect on Ubuntu, in case driver is not available that printer will not show whereas higher model i.e HP CLJ 4303 is detecting with same HPLIP version. Please help me to clarify whether HP CLJ 3303 is supported on HPLIP or not.

I'm using a HP Laserjet on two instances of Ubuntu 22.04 and on Debian 12 and none has HPLIP installed but the OS finds the printer in each case without installing any additional drivers.
